# Adding new div every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page where the user can create a question form where they add questions by themselves and change the type of questions they want to ask. Pretty much the same as Google Forms. Based on the type of question, a box should appear beneath the question that is created. When I try to do this, the box only appears on the last question, so i believe it is overwritten every time a new question is added. Any tips on how to create box beneath every question?

```js
function createQuest() {
  number++;
  chooseTime();

  outputQuestion += '<div id="question' + number + '>';
  outputQuestion += '<p id="k"></p>';
  outputQuestion += '<h2>Question' + number + '</h2>';
  outputQuestion += '<form name="choose">';
  outputQuestion += '<textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="question' + number + '" name="text" placeholder="Question"></textarea>';
  outputQuestion += '<select id="sel' + number + '">';
  outputQuestion += '<option id="' + number + '" id="TEXT" onclick()>Text</option>';
  outputQuestion += '<option id="' + number + '" id="SLIDER">Rating</option>';
  outputQuestion += '</select>';


  outputQuestion += '<ul id="list-quest' + number + '">';
  outputQuestion += '</ul>';
  outputQuestion += '</form>';
  outputQuestion += '</div>';
  $("#list-create-doc").html(outputQuestion);
  textChosen(number);
}

var outputQuest1 = "";

function textChosen(nr) {
  outputQuest1 = "";

  outputQuest1 += '<div class="textbox" id="txt">';
  outputQuest1 += '<textarea rows="1" cols="30" placeholder="Answered with text"></textarea>';
  outputQuest1 += '</div>';

  var whereAdd = "#list-quest" + nr;
  console.log(whereAdd);
  $(whereAdd).html(outputQuest1);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="createQuest()">Legg til spørsmål</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the current content by using `html()`. Use `append()` to add a new one like this:

```
$("#list-create-doc").append(outputQuestion);
```

Here is the docs for [**jQuery.append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [**jQuery.html**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)!

Comment: This worked, but it caused a new problem. When I press to get a new question now, it adds the earlier questions again at the same time. So instead of just "Question 3" it says question 1 and 2 as well. Appreciate all help.

Comment: @Olekern Can explain more? What do you want to append?

Comment: Okey, so I append outputQuestion, but when I append it again next time, it includes what I appended last time. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Olekern well that's what you wanted. Right? What did you mean by box? The textarea?

Comment: Nevermind. I just had to do a outputQuestion = ""; at the start of the function